# Finding postfix form of infix expressions in a text file

Tags: c++, class, templates, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I am trying to find postfix form of infix expressions. My program should read and calculate it in a given text file. The program reads the file and shows me the infix forms but it does not calculate the postfix form of infix expressions. I cannot understand where is the problem. I mean, I do not know the problem is in main() function or in convertToPostfix function. What should I do to solve this problem?

main function:

```
int main() {

    infixToPostfix<string> exp;
    string getcontent;

    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("infixData.txt");
    if (infile.is_open()) {
        while (!infile.eof()) {
            exp.showInfix();
            infile >> getcontent;
            cout << getcontent << endl;
            exp.convertToPostfix();
            exp.getPfx();
            exp.showPostfix();


        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

And converToPostfix() function:

```
template <class Type>
void infixToPostfix<Type>::convertToPostfix() {


stackType<string> obj;
stackType<char> x;
    int i = 0, j=0;
    while (infx[i] != '\0')
    {
        if ((infx[i] >= 'a' && infx[i] <= 'z') || (infx[i] >= 'A' && infx[i] <= 'Z')) {
            pfx[j] += infx[i];
        }
        else if (infx[i] == '('){
            obj.push("(");
    }
        else if (infx[i] == ')') {
            while (obj.top() != "(")
            {
                pfx += obj.top();
                obj.pop();
            }
            if (obj.top() == "(")
                obj.pop();
        }
        else{
            while (precedence(x.top(), infx[i]))
            {
                pfx += obj.top();
                obj.pop();
                j++;
            }
            obj.push(infx);

        }
        i++;
    }
    cout << pfx << endl;
}
```

my "infixData.txt" file:

```
A+B-C;
(A+B)*C;
(A+B)*(C-D);
A+((B+C)*(E-F)-G)/(H-I);
A+B*(C+D)-E/F*G+H;
2+4-1;
(6+3)*2;
```

showInfix():

```
template <class Type>
void infixToPostfix<Type>::showInfix()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Infix expression: " << infx;

}
```

Comment: Certainly the main function is very strange. You seem to be reading the infix expression into a variable called `getcontent`, is that correct? But your `convertToPostfix` routine operates on a variable called `infx`, and no clue is given how that is set up. More code is needed. As well as details on what is in the file infixData.txt.

Comment: And then there is the strange method `showInfix` with no clue given as to what that might be doing. Overall the code looks disorganised and obscure, but there isn't enough information to diagnose exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be a problem of code organisation. You simply aren't using the variables in your program in a way that can possibly work. You are reading the file into one variable, but using a completely different variable to try and solve the problem.

This is what you should do, read the infix expression into a variable in main, then you  **pass that variable as a parameter** to the function that calculates the postfix expression. Like this

```
        infile >> getcontent;
        cout << getcontent << endl;
        convertToPostfix(getcontext);
```

Then `convertToPostfix` should be a function that looks like this

```
void convertToPostfix(const std::string& infx) {
    ...
}
```

There is no need to have a class called `infixToPostfix`, just write functions to do the work, not classes.

And you really need to read about, how to write functions, how to pass parameters to functions and return values from functions. This is a very basic skill. At the moment you clearly don't understand it, but it's absolutely crucial that you do.

Your code also includes lots of advanced features like classes and templates which are unnecessary for this task, and in any case shouldn't be used when you haven't mastered the basics yet.

I'm guessing that you copied the `convertToPostfix` function from somewhere. You should be aware that it doesn't quite solve the problem you have been given. The format of the strings it handles are a just little different from the format of the strings you have. I wonder if you can see the difference?